# What type should be error in Next.js API route handler?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have this API route handler:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import dbConnect from "@/lib/dbConnect";
import User from "@/models/User";

interface ErrorMessage {
    message: string;
}

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, { params }: { params: { id: string } }) {
    await dbConnect();
    const { id } = params;

    try {
        const user = await User.findById(id)

        return NextResponse.json({
            success: true,
            data: user,
        }, {
            status: 200,
        })
    } catch (error: ErrorMessage) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        }, {
            status: 404,
        })
    }
}
```

When I hover or Error, it gives me a TypeScript error `Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if specified.ts(1196)`. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

I'm new to TypeScript so I don't know the best TypeScript practices. I'm using Next.js 13.4.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there could be any kind of exception being thrown, it must be typed (if typed) accordingly with "any" or "unknown" (better: omit it).

One option:
There are "user defined type guard" functions we can write to check types. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Example:

```
function isErrorMessage(error: any): error is ErrorMessage {
  return typeof error?.message === "string";
}

try {
  //[...]
} catch (error) {
  if(isErrorMessage(error)){
    return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: error.message
      },
      { status: 404 }
    );
  }else{
    //example what we could do, if we do not know the error
    console.error(error)
    return NextResponse.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'internal server error'
      },
      { status: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```